# how to get score of each fold in 10 fold cross-validation in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

param=ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.regParam,[0.1,0.01,0.001]).addGrid(lr.maxIter,

[5,10,15,20]).build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,estimatorParamMaps=param,evaluator=evaluator,
numFolds=10,collectSubModels=True)

model_df = crossval.fit(train)
pred=model.transform(test)

not able to get each fold accuracy?